# How to throw custom exceptions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know how to throw custom exception messages in Codeigniter when some situations like the following happen:

1. Connection to database failed for some reason**(I intentionally gave a non-existent database name in my application/config/database.php file to test and tried to do try-catch on $this->db->get() but it did not work. Codeigniter gave its own error message)**

2.A method fails to execute.
I tried to do something like ::

```
try
{
  $this->model_name->myfunc();//myfunc is a non-existent method but any other reason for failure should be handled too using custom message
}catch(Exception $e)
{
   echo "Method failed to run";
}
```

**This did not worked too**

Answer (score 0):

There so many kind of exceptions, maybe you'll need to catch for example a mysqli_sql_exception

```
      try{
       // some code to connect to db
     }catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e)
     { 
       return 'Custom message';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can try the `throw new Exception`, like so:

```
try
{
  $this->model_name->myfunc();//myfunc is a non-existent method but any other reason for failure should be handled too using custom message
}catch(\Exception $e)
{
   throw new \Exception("Method failed to run");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But this technique is not working.Following message was shown:An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method model_name::myfunc()

Comment: You'll also need to exit the root namespace, so write exception this way: `\Exception`